# Обьясните значение

Tags: java

Обьясните значение этого конструкотора, зачем он нужен и что он делает?
[image: конструктор выделен рыжим цветом]

Comment: создает один объект на основе другого.

Comment: Это конструктор. Когда создаётся объект, то сразу же выполняется этот метод (если был передан соответствующий параметр). В этом примере, поле `sum` второго объекта будет хранить `sum` первого. Т.е. при создании экземпляра объекта `s1` выполнится первый метод `Summation(int num)...`, который посчитает саму сумму, а при создании `s2` - второй, ибо как уже сказано выше параметры переданы разные.

Comment: Я тоже умею читать, но не понимаю как это все работает

Comment: если у тебя есть экземпляр класса Summation (назовём его s1), у которого хранится в поле sum (s1.sum) значение 10, то при выполнении такого кода, как Summation s2 = new Summation(s1), у s2 поле sum (s2.sum) так же будет равно 10 (как и у s1)

Comment: а вообще можешь написать код, что выше в комментарии и поставить точки остановки (debug) в этом конструкторе и в участке, где ты создаешь новый экземпляр

Answer (score 1):

Это так называемый "конструктор копирования", который возвращает копию объекта (объект с таким же содержимым, не путать с копией ссылки на один объект). Т.е. В конструктор мы подаем объект и создаем новый объект с такими же значениями полей, как у поданного объекта. 
Подробнее можно почитать в у Блоха в Effective Java, там же он рекомендует пользоваться таким конструктором вместо метода clone().